# group invoices with transaction value greater or smaller then zero

Tags: sql, join

Im trying to make a query out of this but im having no luck yet. The tables are as following:

```
INVOICE
ID | INVOICENUMBER | CUSTOMER | VALUE
1 | 999 | 8 | 9000
2 | 999 | 8 | 1000


INVOICE_TRANSACTION
InvoiceID | TYPE | VALUE
1 | cust | 5000
1 | cust | 2000
2 | cust | 1000
2 | cust | -1000

INVOICE_DETAIL
InvoiceID | PURCHASEORDERID
1 | 7777

PURCHASE_ORDER
PURCHASEORDERID | ORDERTYPE
7777 | gross

PURCASE_ORDER_DETAILS
PURCHASEORDERID | ROW | STATUS
7777 | 1 | 1
7777 | 2 | 2
7777 | 3 | 3
```

The result I want is this:

```
INVOICE VALUE TRANSACTION VALUE PURCHASEORDERID ORDERTYPE HIGH STATUS LOW STATUS
------- ----- ----------------- --------------- --------- ----------- ----------
1       9000  7000              7777            gross     3           1
```

In other words I want the result to group all invoice numbers that has a total `invoice_transaction.value` greater or smaller then 0. I'm new to all this, can anyone give me a hand to get me started?

Comment: I highly recommend creating a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for this.

Comment: What sql(mysql, postgre, ms sql) are you using? And what version?

Comment: `group by`, and `having trans_value <> 0`. the rest is left as an exercise to the OP

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want something like this:

```
select i.id,
  sum(i.value) value,
  it.value TransValue,
  p.purchaseorderid,
  p.ordertype,
  pd.highstatus,
  pd.lowstatus
from invoice i
left join 
(
  select sum(value) value, invoiceid
  from invoice_transaction
  group by invoiceid
) it
  on i.id = it.invoiceid
left join invoice_detail id
  on i.id = id.invoiceid
left join purchase_order p
  on id.purchaseorderid = p.purchaseorderid
left join
(
  select max(status) highStatus, min(status) LowStatus,
    purchaseorderid
  from purcase_order_details
  group by purchaseorderid
) pd
  on p.purchaseorderid = pd.purchaseorderid
where it.value <> 0
group by i.id, p.purchaseorderid, p.ordertype;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/613c0/23)

Answer (score 0):

To get the invoice ids from INVOICE_TRANSACTION where value is not zero,

```
SELECT InvoiceID
FROM INVOICE_TRANSACTION
GROUP BY InvoiceID
HAVING SUM(VALUE) <> 0
```